# Slideshow com imagens BLOB do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Estou montando um gerenciador de imagens e preciso exibir essas imagens numa TV, através do navegador por um slideshow.

Eu consigo montar um slide show setando cada endereço da imagem, porém tenho várias imagens no DB, e precisaria criar um array de imagens para fazer com que o *slideshow* pegue essas imagens do array de imagens que tenho no MySQL.

Seguem meus códigos:

exibe.php (exibe a imagem na tela, está exibindo uma embaixo da outra)

```
<?
//CONECTA AO MYSQL                                               
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tv"); 

//EXECUTA A QUERY                                                
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id_msg, img, departamento FROM mensagem");   

echo "<h2>Exibe imagens cadastradas no BD</h2>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {   
$id    = $row[0];                         
$bytes = $row[1];                         
$tipo  = $row[2];                         

echo "<img src='gera.php?id_msg=".$id."' width='200' height='300' border='1'>";

echo "<br><br></div>";
}


?>
```

gera.php (geras todas as imagens do banco de dados para serem exibidas pelo `exibe.php`)

```
<?php

//RECEBE PARÂMETRO  
$id = $_GET["id_msg"];  

//CONECTA AO MYSQL                                               
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Sat3t3ll", "tv"); 

//EXIBE IMAGEM                                                                        
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT img FROM mensagem WHERE id_msg = ".$id."");         

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);    
//$tipo   = $row["tipo"];                        
$bytes  = $row["img"];                        
//EXIBE IMAGEM                                 
header( "Content-type: image/gif");              
echo $bytes;

?>
```

Minha ideia seria utilizar esse *slideshow* para exibir o *array* de imagens gerado pelo `exibe.php`

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/jcycle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function() {
$('#slideShow').cycle({ fx: 'fade' });
});
// -->
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="slideShow">
<img src="img/foto1.jpg" alt="Primeira Foto" width="300" height="200" />
<img src="img/foto2.jpg" alt="Segunda Foto" width="300" height="200" />
<img src="img/foto3.jpg" alt="Terceira Foto" width="300" height="200" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O problema é exibir as imagens(não aparecem)? ou apenas uma imagem é mostrado no seu exemplo?

Comment: As imagens aparecem, o problema é que ele pega a primeira imagem e aplica o efeito, nas demais fica uma em cima da outra. Vou postar o código na web. 1 min.

Comment: Estou com problemas para subir online. Veja uma imagem de exemplo: http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/capturar-jpg--663 Na imagem 1 o efeito é aplicado, porém as outras imagens ficam em baixo. A ideia seria juntar todas essas imagens uma sobre a outra e aplicar o efeito do slideshow. Estou usando o Cycle para fazer o slide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode exibir a imagem direto do banco(stream) direto na tag `<img>` usando o atribuito `src`dessa forma: `data:image/jpg;base64,stream_codificado....`

No exibe.php faça um array com todas as imagens, depois utilize ele na página do slide.

exibe.php

```
$imagens = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {   
   $imagens[] = $row;
}
```

No arquivo que tem os slides, talvez seja preciso fazer um include de exibe.php:

```
<div id="slideShow">
<?php
    foreach($imagens as $item){
       $img_template = '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. $item[1]. '" alt="Primeira Foto" width="300" height="200" />';
       echo $img_template;
    }
?>
</div>
```

Baseado em :

[PHP show image as BLOB mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27044721/1342547)

[Displaying a base64 image from database via php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16262098/1342547)

[How to decode a base64 string (gif) into image in PHP / HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4110907/1342547)

Comment: Só evite usar este método se for imprimir muitas imagens. `base64_encode` vai imprimir uma quantidade bem grande de texto o que pode dar uma "engasgada" no browser na hora do carregamento.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro, correto, caso sejam muitas imagens é melhor pegar o stream transformar em um arquivo e carregar o nome no `src`.

Comment: Pessoal deu certo. Só tive que mudar de base64_enconde para base64_decode. No enconde estava gerando varios caracteres estranhos. Só tenho uma dúvida agora. Ele pega as 3 imagens que tenho, porém no final ele mostra o icone de uma imagem corrompida, veja: http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/capturar-jpg--665

Comment: Descobrir, era só tirar o echo $img_template; do código do slide.php, porque ele já está setado no exibe.php. Valeu mais uma vez. segue código completo para quem quiser, link: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx7OPztNLuy4d0djT1QyUHh3Vlk&usp=sharing

Comment: Pessoal, estou com uma dificuldade. Estou fazendo a seguinte consulta no banco: SELECT id_msg, img FROM mensagem WHERE '$hoje' BETWEEN data_inicio and data_termino, onde $hoje pega a data atual, só irei exibir na tela o que for correspondente a data inicial e data final. A query da certo, porém o  array está sendo montado com uma imagem totalmente em branco, que é a imagem que está ficando fora do select. Alguem sabe como posso resolver isso?

Comment: @Renato_Souza_Delphi, talvez seja melhora fazer outra pergunta descrevendo esse problema e seus detalhes.

Comment: Como esta aqui está sendo usada como canônica de várias duplicatas, acho que merece um edit pra acrescentar a possibilidade de header ( image.... + blob com dados nativos, sem essa coisa de inflar com base64), assim ficaria bem completa