# PDO Seleção no banco de dados mysql parametro BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estou com problema ao tentar resgatar uma ou uma lista de imagens que já inseri no mysql 5 com PDO.
tenho uma classe dao que tem a arquitetura de minhas querys para trabalhar com o banco de dados.

```
class ImagemDao {

public function inserirImagem(ImagemEntity $imagem) {
    $conexao = ...
    $stmt = $conexao->getStance()->prepare("INSERT INTO imagem(imagem,id_pagina) VALUES(:img, :idPagina)");
    $stmt->bindValue(":img", $imagem->getImagem());
    $stmt->bindValue(":idPagina", $imagem->getIdPagina());
    $stmt->execute();
    
}
public function selecionaTodasImagens() {
    $conexao = ...
    $consulta = $conexao->getStance()->query("SELECT id_imagem, imagem, id_pagina FROM imagem;");
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        
        echo $linha->id_imagem ."</br>" ;
        echo $linha->imagem ."</br>";
        echo $linha->id_pagina ."</br>";
    
    }
}
```

minha bean está da seguinte forma.

```
class ImagemEntity {
private $id;
private $imagem;
private $idPagina;
function __construct($id = "", $imagem = "", $idPagina = "") {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->imagem = $imagem;
    $this->idPagina = $idPagina;
}
 //get and set
```

e tenho um arquivo de teste

```
<?php 
    $dao = new ImagemDao();
    $dao->selecionaTodasImagens();

?>
```

o que ele me retorna são apenas o texto da imagem e seu id mas nenhuma visualização.

minha entidade do banco está da seguinte forma.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no browser está mostrando da seguinte forma.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48325/slideshow-com-imagens-blob-do-mysql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja [PDO - Large Objects (LOBs)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) .

Basicamente faltou passar a constante `PDO::PARAM_LOB`na hora de fazer binding...

```
$stmt->bindValue(":img", $imagem->getImagem(), PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

Claro que estou assumindo que `$imagem->getImagem()` foi previamente inicializado com um arquivo ou algo do gênero (se você apenas passar o nome da imagem nada vai acontecer).