# Exibir imagem salva em BLOB

Tags: php, imagem, blob

Gostaria de saber como faço para exibir uma imagem salva no banco de dados em BLOB:

codigo:

```
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$preco = $_POST["preco"];
$cor = $_POST["cor"];
$descricao = $_POST["descricao"];

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']))
{
 $imgData = file_get_contents($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']);
 $sizeData = getimagesize($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']);
 $imagem = $imgData;
}
if(insereProduto($conexao, $nome, $preco, $imagem, $descricao, $cor)) { 

    ?><p class="text-success">Produto  <?=$nome ?>, que custa <?=$preco?> adicionado com sucesso!</p><?php


}

function insereProduto($conexao, $nome, $preco, $imagem, $descricao, $cor) {
   $query = "insert into produtos (nome, preco, imagem, descricao, cor) values 
   ('{$nome}', '{$preco}','{$imagem}', '{$descricao}','{$cor}')"; 
   echo $query;
   $resultadoDaInsercao = mysqli_query($conexao, $query); 
   return $resultadoDaInsercao; 
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicada de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48325/slideshow-com-imagens-blob-do-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exibir imagens a partir do BD você tem que alterar o header da página para o navegador entender que é uma imagem. Para tal crie um arquivo gera.php que será responsável por gerar a imagem de forma que o navegador a entenda como imagem e chame essa página no atributo src da tag html img. Dessa forma:

Gera.php

```
  <?
//RECEBE
PARÂMETRO 
$id = $_GET["id"];

//CONECTA
AO MYSQL 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario",
"senha", "base de dados ");

//EXIBE
IMAGEM 
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT foto,tipo FROM
fotos WHERE id = ".$id."");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,
MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
$tipo = $row["tipo"]; 
$bytes = $row["foto"];

//EXIBE
IMAGEM 
header("Content-type: ".$tipo."");

echo $bytes;
?>
```

Exibir:

```
  echo "<img src=”gera.php?id=".$id."”";
```

Answer (score -1):

vc tem pode printar diretamente na imagem codificando em base64

```
echo base64_decode($data);
echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $data . '" />';
```

onde o $data he a imagem que veio direto do db

Comment: Pra isso funcionar: `echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode($data) . '" />';` (**caso o BLOB não esteja codificado em base64**) ou `echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . $data . '" />';` (**caso o BLOB esteja codificado em base64**). Nenhuma das duas formas precisa do `echo base64_decode($data);`.