# Como exibir imagem armazenada em tipo blob

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob

Tenho um banco de dados que possui um campo blob. Esse campo é pra ter uma foto. Preciso chamar essa foto e exibir ela. 
Eu não possuo as fotos que deram origem ao conteúdo do banco de dados, por isso é inviável trabalhar linkando o endereço. Sei que não é uma boa prática, mas é o que eu tenho.
Quando dou um `echo` para exibir o conteúdo do que está salvo no campo blob ele retorna algo como `0x00000001000000a7`. Presciso transformar esses números em uma imagem e exibir ela como se fosse um `<img>` do html.
Andei pesquisando e já tinha visto o caso [Slideshow com imagens BLOB do MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48325/slideshow-com-imagens-blob-do-mysql) mas não sei por qual motivo não funciona comigo.

Comment: O ideal seria você fazer o upload do arquivo em uma pasta e salvar o o nome do arquivo que foi feito upload no banco de dados, e depois, quando for exibir a imagem, selecionar o nome do arquivo.

Comment: O problema é que eu não tenho as imagens, só o banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Bom uma das maneira que você pode usar e esse código aqui ele pega o update e salva na pasta da sua aplicação e nomeia a foto com o id do usuario depois e so recuperar a foto da pasta e pronto. Código bem simples e funcional! qualquer coisa so falar

```
<?php
    session_start();

        $PHP_SELF = "";
        //Diretório aonde ficará os arquivos
        $dir = "./image/users/profile_photo/";

        //Extensões permitidas
        $ext = array("gif","jpg","png");

        //Quant. de campos do tipo FILE
        $campos = 6;

        //Formulário
        echo '<form method="post" action="'.$PHP_SELF.'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file[]">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" OK ">
     </form>';


    //Se for enviado
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Obtendo info. dos arquivos
    $f_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $f_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $f_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];


    //Contar arquivos enviados
    $cont=0;

    //Repetindo de acordo com a quantidade de campos FILE
    for($i=0;$i<$campos;$i++){

    //Pegando o nome
    $name = $_SESSION['usuarioID'];

    //Verificando se o campo contem arquivo
      if ( ($name!="") and (is_file($f_tmp[$i])) and (in_array(substr($name, -3),$ext)) ) {

        if ($cont==0) {
          echo "<b>Arquivo(s) enviados:
    </b>";
        }
          echo $name." - ";

          //Movendo arquivo's do upload
          $up = move_uploaded_file($f_tmp[$i], $dir.$name);

            //Status
            if ($up==true):
                echo  "<i>Enviado!</i>";
                  $cont++;
            else:
                echo "<i>Falhou!</i>";
            endif;

          echo "
    ";
      }

    }

    echo ($cont!=0) ? "<i>Total de arquivos enviados: </i>".$cont : "Nenhum arquivo foi enviado!";
    }
    ?>
```

sim e possível fazer a tag img receber o caminho EX:

```
<div class="perfil">
  <img src="/image/users/profile_photo/<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['usuarioID']; ?>.jpg">
  <img>
</div>
```

Comment: O problema é que eu não tenho as imagens que deram "origem" ao banco de dados.

Comment: @RafaelPessoa explique melhor a pergunta não entendi

Comment: Eu tenho um banco de dados com um campo blob que são referentes a algumas fotos, porém eu não tenho as fotos em um arquivo separado. Só o que está no banco de dados. Preciso fazer essas fotos serem exibidas em um campo <img> para fazer semelhante a uma identidade.

Comment: $querry= $conexao_pdo->prepare("SELECT *FROM tabela "); 
$querry->execute();
$result = $querry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                                                                                                                                            foreach($querry as $result ){  echo"<img src='/image/users/profile_photo/$result['campo_da_imagem'];'>
  <img>"  }  tenta seguir esse raciocinio aqui @RafaelPessoa